# Checking values for an array for every $i

Tags: php, arrays

I have a for-loop

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
($n equals 100)
```

and an array containing values.

```
$BidsEachHour = array(4,8,13,17......96)
```

What I want to do is that for every $i equal to $BidsEachHour is do a specific check.

How can I check if $i equals $BidsEachHour for every value of $BidsEachHour?

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
    if(in_array($i,$BidsEachHour)) {
        echo "Yeah, found ".$i." in array!";
    }
```

Doesn't work.

More info:

```
$BidsEachHour[] = Hourlybids();
```

Function

```
Function Hourlybids (){
Global $tagloads;
$BidsEachHour = array();

for($k=0; $k < 24; $k++){
$BidsEachHour[$k] = round($k/24*$tagloads);
}
//var_dump($BidsEachHour);
Return $BidsEachHour;
}
```

Comment: `if(in_array($i, $BidsEachHour)) {` - http://uk1.php.net/in_array

Comment: @Titanium Doesn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Technically that's impossible. `$i` is an integer while `$BidsEachHour` is an array. They will never be equal. You're probably trying to do what @Titanium already said.

Comment: You're probably just using it wrong OP

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat I tried it, doesn't work. It is called inside a function, I made sure that function is called and everything else in the function works just fine. This code doesn't work for me. Or is there anyway I misuse this type of code?

Comment: just post your new code and somebody here will surely have a look on it.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Updated, I checked if the array was empty, but it was filled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
    if(in_array($i,$BidsEachHour)) {
        echo "Yeah, found ".$i." in array!";
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
$BidsEachHour[] = HourlyBids()
```

must be

```
$BidsEachHour = HourlyBids()
```

Comment: Does not give me any results. It doesn't echo anything out, yet doesn't give me any errors

Comment: Can you post you code snippet, what you tried? It should work as I provided.

Comment: I tried in_array myself and was surprised it didn't work. I am not running any checks yet. Just copy pasted your code within my for loop. What code snippet do you want to have a look at?

Comment: $BidsEachHour is declared before the for-loop call?

Comment: Yes it is, var_dumped it in both the for loop and before the for loop. Both are filled.

Comment: Can you post the var_dump?

Comment: What if you try to change `$BidsEachHour[] = HourlyBids()` to `$BidsEachHour = HourlyBids()`

Comment: That works, thanks a bunch! Any idea why that worked and mine didn't?

Comment: Well $BidsEachHour[] adds a value to a $BidsEachHour array. But your function gives you an array back, so you would add an array into an array.

Answer (score -1):

Why not directly looping over the array ?

```
foreach($BidsEachHour AS $k) {
    // $k will contain 4,8,13,17......96
    // do a specific check
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but is exclude "else" check